# PHP How to filter array values

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I'm trying to show in a div 3 thumbnails stored in different folders. 
In my bd determined (with value "1") which record has pictures. So this is my db:

```
+------+----------------+---------+--------+--------+
| ID   | BRAND          |   PHP   |  RUBY  |  JAVA  |
+------+----------------+---------+--------+--------+
| 1    | ford           |    1    |    0   |    0   |
+------+----------------+---------+--------+--------+
| 2    | seat           |    1    |    1   |    1   |
+------+----------------+---------+--------+--------+
| 3    | fiat           |    1    |    1   |    0   |
+------+----------------+---------+--------+--------+
| 4    | toyota         |    1    |    0   |    0   |
+------+----------------+---------+--------+--------+
| 5    | vw             |    1    |    0   |    1   |
+------+----------------+---------+--------+--------+
```

Selecting records:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT * FROM brands WHERE php = '1' OR ruby = '1' OR java = '1' ORDER BY id ASC");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $new_array[] = $row;
}
```

But my problem is: How I can select the values ​​"1" and how to know which is which?
Maybe I could use: `$row['php'] $row['java'] $row['ruby']` But how to filter the values ​​"0"?

Comment: tip: simplify your query with `WHERE 1 IN (PHP, RUBY, JAVA)`.

Comment: Just loop through each one with an if($row['ruby'])... what are you wanting to do if it is a one?

Comment: @cwhelms With the value "1" say there is a folder with images that correspond to the record. Example: directory php-> folder 1 (id of ford), folder 2 (id of seat), ruby directory -> folder 3 (id of fiat) etc. So should have a "while" or "foreach" with this data and display a url depending on the values ​​"1" in the array: folder/'.$code.'/'.$id.'/

Comment: @Jon Perhaps there is some way to simplify many if(php) if(ruby) if(java)? thank you

Comment: @santyas: Not really unless I 'm missing something. You can of course hide the conditionals inside a method, which often is a good way to increase both the abstraction and readability of your code at the expense of a tiny performance hit that you probably don't care about (exchanging something you don't need for something you do is a common attribute of good engineering). But the logic still needs to exist somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to break up the array into php, java, and ruby. Below is not tested, just to give you an idea.

```
$resultsArray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($row['php'] == 1) {
        $resultsArray['php'][] = $row['id'];
    }
    if($row['java'] == 1) {
        $resultsArray['java'][] = $row['id'];
    }
    if($row['ruby'] == 1) {
        $resultsArray['ruby'][] = $row['id'];
    }
}
```

Then loop through that 2d array, grabbing the name from the key in resultsArray.

```
foreach($resultsArray as $language => $array) {
    foreach($array as $id) {
        echo "url/".$language."/".$id;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Like this? `foreach($resultsArray as $key => $val){print_r($val);}`

Comment: Look at my edit. print_r will only get you the array of an individual language.

Comment: Hello again, works perfect. I use it with a single foreach and the id in this way: `echo "url/".$language."/".$row['id'];` I can ask you something else? Surely you understand the concept and I take long to reformulate a new post. How I can use `opendir` with directories I got? Thank you very much!

Comment: I could write the names of the files that are inside the folders, but I do not know the names. So I need to use readdir @cwhelms

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($resultsArray as $language => $array){
    foreach(array_slice(glob('work/'.$language.'/'.$rowtest['id'].'/*.jpg'),0,1) as $image){    
        echo $image . "<br />";
    }
}
```